# If or return statment syntax of javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the meaning of :

```
return i ? null : "red";
```

?
What is the meaning of "?" and ":"

Comment: This question is exactly why we need Google to support symbol-only searches.

Comment: @Polynomial: http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=%3F+%3A

Comment: @DavidHedlund I'm aware of SymbolHound, but most people aren't. We could avoid a lot of questions here if Google would support it.

Comment: @Polynomial: true! Although a questions 'googleability' doesn't always correlate with its chances of ending up on SO anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a ternary operation.

Its syntax is:

```
condition ? operation-if-true : operation-if-false
```

For instance

```
return myVariable >5 ? 'a' : 'b';
```

return "a" if `myVariable` is greater than 5, otherwise "b".